# How to make antivirus ignore my programs?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus

Is there any way to prevent my antivirus from flagging my programs on my computer and slowing their execution by scanning them constantly?

I've written them, so I know they're OK. Disabling antivirus (Windows Defender) is currently not an option, as it is set by group policies.

Whenever I run my program, I can see from task manager that my "antimalware service executable" (Microsoft defender antivirus service) suddenly pops up to ~15% CPU usage, and the execution speed of my program (reading and parsing a bunch of text files) slows down considerably.

Comment: By adding an exclusion?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26#:~:text=Go%20to%20Start%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Update,%2C%20file%20types%2C%20or%20process.